# Using Find to find files with similar names to a list defined in a file. Possible?

Tags: linux, shell, find

Is it possible to use a file containing a list of filenames as a parameter in a 'find' command?

For example,

list.txt:

```
car*
test*
owl*
```

I want the find command to use each entry as part of its '-name' option.

Not sure how to go about this or if its even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bash`, you can build pattern list in an array first then run `find`:

```
arr=()
while read -r arg; do
   arr+=(-name "$arg" -o)
done < list.txt

# run find command with pattern coming from array
find . \( "${arr[@]}" -name '' \)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find accepts multiple `-name`. Using the `-o` option for `OR`

```
find . -name "car*" -o -name "test*" -o -name "owl*"
```